# Timeline Google Charts hAxis resolution java javascript GWT

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, google-visualization

Hi i have a googlee timeline chart

```
 private static native Promise setDataToChart(Object[] objects1)/*-{
        // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
        $wnd.google.charts.load("current", {packages: ["timeline"]});
        $wnd.google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart(objects1));

        function drawChart(obj1) {
            var container = $wnd.document.getElementById('timeline');
            var chart = new $wnd.google.visualization.Timeline(container);
            var dataTable = new $wnd.google.visualization.DataTable();
            dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', id: 'Role'});
            dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', id: 'Name'});
            dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', id: 'style', role: 'style'});
            dataTable.addColumn({type: 'date', id: 'Start'});
            dataTable.addColumn({type: 'date', id: 'End'});

            dataTable.addRows(obj1);

            var options = {
                title: 'Rate the Day on a Scale of 1 to 10',

                hAxis: {
                    format: 'dd/MM/yyyy'
                }
            };

            chart.draw(dataTable, options);

            // Hide empthy items
            var rects = $wnd.document.getElementsByTagName('rect');
            for (var i = 0; i < rects.length; i++) {
                if (rects[i].getAttribute("fill") === "#f44336") {
                    rects[i].setAttribute("display", "none");
                }
            }
        }

    }-*/;
```

[image: result]

As you could notice in the picture, he is using the same day twice on X-axis, howto set the scale to 1 day instead of 2 or 4 ?

Thanks in advance